# How do I flatMap a row of arrays into multiple rows?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

After parsing some jsons I have a one-column DataFrame of arrays

```
scala> val jj =sqlContext.jsonFile("/home/aahu/jj2.json")
res68: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [r: array<bigint>]
scala> jj.first()
res69: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)]
```

I'd like to explode each row out into several rows. How?

**edit:**

Original json file:

```
{"r": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
{"r": [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
```

I want an RDD or a DataFrame with 20 rows.

I can't simply use flatMap here - I'm not sure what the appropriate command in spark is:

```
scala> jj.flatMap(r => r)
<console>:22: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Row
 required: TraversableOnce[?]
              jj.flatMap(r => r)
```

Comment: please post the original json example and the example of the result you are expecting

Comment: @vvladymyrov it's in the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.explode` to achieve what you desire. Below is what I tried in spark-shell with your sample json data.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
val jj1 = jj.explode("r", "r1") {list : ArrayBuffer[Long] => list.toList }
val jj2 = jj1.select($"r1")
jj2.collect
```

You can refer to API documentation to understand more `DataFrame.explode`

Comment: What version of spark/scala are you on? I am using 1.4 in local mode and get java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer when I try this

Answer (score 3):

I've tested this with Spark 1.3.1
Or you can use Row.getAs function:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
val elementsRdd = jj.select(jj("r")).map(t=>t.getAs[ArrayBuffer[Long]](0)).flatMap(x=>x)
elementsRdd.count()
>>>Long = 20
elementsRdd.take(5)
>>>Array[Long] = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Spark 1.3+ you can use `explode` function directly on the column of interest:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode

jj.select(explode($"r"))
```