# How do I flatMap a row of arrays into multiple rows in Apache spark using Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a json data file which contain one property which is string arrays of "tags". The Apache Spark **DataFrame** schema look like below:

```
root
 |-- acceptedAnswerId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- answerCount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- body: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score: long (nullable = true)
 |-- <b>tags</b>: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- viewCount: long (nullable = true)
```

I'd like to explode each row out into several rows in **Java**. I can find similar answer using [**Scala**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833618/how-do-i-flatmap-a-row-of-arrays-into-multiple-rows) but not able to convert the solution in Java. Any suggestion?

The "tags" property in JSON look like:

```
"tags":["c#",".net","compression","decompression"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to make the solution more visualize, the sample json data look like below:

```
{"id":4,"score":358,"viewCount":24247,"answerCount":13,"commentCount":1,"favoriteCount":28,"tags":["c#","winforms","type-conversion","opacity"]}
```

Below is the Java code snippet to read the json data as "DataFrame" object:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);

String jsonData = "{\"id\":4,\"score\":358,\"viewCount\":24247,\"tags\":[\"c#\",\"winforms\",\"type-conversion\",\"opacity\"]}";    
    
List dataSet = Arrays.asList(jsonData);

JavaRDD distData = sc.parallelize(dataSet);

DataFrame stackoverflow_Posts = sqlContext.read().json(distData);

stackoverflow_Posts.printSchema(); //let's print out the DataFrame schema (Output#1)

stackoverflow_Posts.show(); //let's show the DataFrame content (Ouput#2)
```

The schema: *Output#1* looks like below:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- score: long (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- viewCount: long (nullable = true)
```

The data: *Output#2* looks like below:

```
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+
| id|score|                tags|viewCount|
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+
|  4|  358|[c#, winforms, ty...|    24247|
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+
```

Base on [zero323](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1560062/zero323)'s information, I continue to process:

```
DataFrame expanded = stackoverflow_Posts.withColumn("tag", org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(stackoverflow_Posts.col("tags")));
        
expanded.printSchema(); //let's print out the DataFrame schema again (Output#3)
        
expanded.show(); //let's show the DataFrame content (Output#4)
```

The schema: *Output#3* looks like below:

```
root
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- score: long (nullable = true)
 |-- tags: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- viewCount: long (nullable = true)
 |-- tag: string (nullable = true)
```

And the data after **explode** : *Output#4*

```
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+---------------+
| id|score|                tags|viewCount|            tag|
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+---------------+
|  4|  358|[c#, winforms, ty...|    24247|             c#|
|  4|  358|[c#, winforms, ty...|    24247|       winforms|
|  4|  358|[c#, winforms, ty...|    24247|type-conversion|
|  4|  358|[c#, winforms, ty...|    24247|        opacity|
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+---------------+
```

The result looks very similar like using SQL to join two table.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `explode` function.

```
DataFrame df = ...
DataFrame expanded = df.withColumn(
  "tag", org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode(df.col("tags"))).drop("tags");
```