# Flattening the key of a RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, flatmap

I have a Spark RDD of type `(Array[breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double]], breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double])`. I wish to flatten its key to transform it into a RDD of type `breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double], breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double])`. I am currently doing:

```
val newRDD = oldRDD.flatMap(ob => anonymousOrdering(ob))
```

The signature of anonymousOrdering() is `String => (Array[DenseVector[Double]], DenseVector[Double])`.

It returns `type mismatch: required: TraversableOnce[?]`. The Python code doing the same thing is:

```
newRDD = oldRDD.flatMap(lambda point: [(tile, point) for tile in anonymousOrdering(point)])
```

How to do the same thing in Scala ? I generally use `flatMapValues`but here I need to flatten the key.

Comment: Could you specify the signature of `anonymousOrdering`? Also after flattening the type of the RDD is the same in your question. Is that intentional?

Comment: Signature added (comment in the first snippet), my intention is to transform a RDD containing (Array(1, 2), 3) into a RDD containing (1, 3) | (2, 3). I have replaced the type DenseVector by an integer for this example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do:

```
val newRDD = oldRDD.flatMap(ob => anonymousOrdering(ob))
// newRDD is RDD[(Array[DenseVector], DenseVector)]
```

In that case, you can "flatten" the `Array` portion of the tuple using pattern matching and a `for`/`yield` statement:

```
newRDD = newRDD.flatMap{case (a: Array[DenseVector[Double]], b: DenseVector[Double]) => for (v <- a) yield (v, b)}
// newRDD is RDD[(DenseVector, DenseVector)]
```

Although it's still not clear to me where/how you want to use `groupByKey`

Comment: I am removing the groupByKey() at the end of the map as it is not related to the question. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: val newRDD = oldRDD.flatMap(ob => anonymousOrdering(ob)) returns `found   : (Array[breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double]], breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double]), required: TraversableOnce[?]`

Comment: Looks like the issue is inside of `anonymousOrdering` then... See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30833618/how-do-i-flatmap-a-row-of-arrays-into-multiple-rows

Comment: The method used in the link is not available for RDDs, only DataFrames.

Comment: It was a link for reference, not a solution--I can't debug your `anonymousOrdering` function just by looking at the type signature and error. Your original question was about flattening keys, maybe re-accept this and ask a new question?

Comment: Yes sorry, I will write a new question and the answer soon as this one was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to use Map instead of FlatMap:

```
val newRDD = oldRDD.map(ob => anonymousOrdering(ob)).groupByKey()
```

You would only want to use flatmap here if anonymousOrdering returned a list of tuples and you wanted it flattened down.

Comment: Mapping will return a RDD of type (Array[breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double]], breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double]), I want to flatten the first part of the tuple.

Comment: Can you post the function signature of anonymousOrdering?

Comment: Question updated, it is now below the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

As `anonymousOrdering()` is a function that you have in your code, update it in order to return a `Seq[(breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double], breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double])]`. It is like doing `(tile, point) for tile in anonymousOrdering(point)]` but directly at the end of the anonymous function. The `flatMap` will then take care to create one partition for each element of the sequences.

As a general rule, avoid having a collection as a key in a RDD.

Comment: You asked how to flatten a key, I answered and you accepted my answer, but then you did a workaround for your code so that you don't have to flatten the key anymore, and accepted your workaround as a "solution"... You also never posted the contents of `anonymousOrdering`, which had the actual problem. Bad form!

Comment: I accepted your answer again but it did not work and the real answer is just to not have a RDD with arrays as keys.